# How to check if button is clicked in LoadViewState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loadviewstate

I want to check if button is clicked in LoadViewState

Code:

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
base.LoadViewState(savedState);

//Here If (btnAddExperience_Click()  is clicked)   
{
method1();
} 
//if(btnAddVisa_Click())
{
method2();
}
}

protected void btnAddExperience_Click(sender,e)
{
  //some code
}

protected void btnAddVisa_Click(sender,e)
{
  //some code
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this works in pageload you could try it in loadviewstate

```
if( IsPostBack ) 
{
    // get the target of the post-back, will be the name of the control
    // that issued the post-back
    string eTarget = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response how to get the target of the post-back?